# Linux zombie process Xsession

Tags: linux, zombie-process

I find a zombie process named Xsession in my Linux system,it's father process is GNOME.How does it happen and how to kill this process.

Comment: "How does it happen" is fairly varied.  We can't possibly speculate on your system - we don't know which Distribution you're using, how you're configured, or what packages you've installed.  As far as killing it - do you have the PID?  It's as simple as `kill -9 $PID`.  You'll probably need to be root, so prepend a `sudo` or login as root - whatever your flavor supports.

Comment: @FrankieTheKneeMan A zombie is already dead, so killing it is pointless.  If the process is a zombie, its parent has not waited for it.  If GNOME is not waiting for its children properly, this is a bug in GNOME.

Answer (score 0):

Here... I've been using a modified version of this for a while.

http://www.mariusv.com/automatic-zombie-processes-killing-shell-script/

Cron it to run every x minutes.